# vauxhall vectra cdti sri 150 running problems

Tags: fuel-system

I recently had low fuel pressure problems with my cdti. I took it to a garage and got the high pressure pump changed. After that it started no problem but after 15mins of it running, it started running lumpy and cutting out, so I got the computer on it again and the error that was cumming up was the fuel rail regualter and sensor. So I got them changed as well. The car still isn't running right and cutting out after a few minutes ticking over. Has anybody got an idea what it could be? Could dirty fuel or water in the fuel cause this???

Comment: More likely water, but yes.